# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm using Django to develop a platform where users can upload files. This function was working fine for months with no issues, but for some reason now I get this error when trying to upload a file:

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/me/project/app/views.py", line 314, in invoke_local
    instance = SingleEndForm(file=request.FILES['file'])

Exception Type: TypeError at /invoke_local/
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'
```

My model:

```
class SingleEnd(models.Model):

    file = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/")
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

My form:

```
class SingleEndForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        # shows which model to use from models.py
        model = SingleEnd
        # fields = '__all__'
        fields = ["file", "email"]

        labels = {
            "file": "input your fasta/fastq file (min 3 sequences)",
            "email": "input your email to get a notification for your results in a timely manner",
        }
        widgets = {
            "email": forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            "file": forms.FileInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
        }
```

My view:

```
def invoke_local(request):
    # path to save inputs
    media_path = "/home/me/project/media/documents/"
    # path to save outputs
    result_path = "/home/me/project/media/results"
   
    if request.method == "POST":
        # use the form to upload form info (post) and files
        form = SingleEndForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # saves full form
            instance = SingleEndForm(file=request.FILES['file'])
            instance.save()

            # changes file name if the name is the same
            file_name_final = instance.file.name[10:]
            # final path
            file_path = media_path + file_name_final
    else:
        raise Http404("Form not entered correctly")
form = SingleEndForm()
return render(request, "invoke_local.html", {"form": form})
```

I really don't get what I've done wrong.

Comment: maybe  you need model `SingleEnd(file=...)` instead of form `SingleEndForm(file=...)`. OR maybe you should use `instance.file = ...`

Comment: @furas as far as i can see in the docs you need to use the form in that part

Comment: and this is why I think you use wrong class - you may need `SingleEnd` instead of `SingleEndForm`. OR maybe you need only `form.save()`

Comment: example in documentation [Handling uploaded files with a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model) uses directly `form.save()`. And next example uses `instance` but this is `Model`, not `Form` - so in this version you have to use model `SingleEnd` instead of `SingleEndForm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on example in documentation [Handling uploaded files with a model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model) you mix two different methods and this makes problem

You can directly write `Form`

```
form = SingleEndForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    # saves full form
    form.save()
```

Or you have to create instance of model `SingleEnd` instead of form `SingleEndForm`

```
form = SingleEndForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
if form.is_valid():
    # use model 
    instance = SingleEnd(file=request.FILES['file'])
    instance.save()
```

(but you use form `SingleEndForm` and this makes problem)